# How to setup Squid Proxy Server for specific purpose?

Tags: server, proxy, squid

I have installed squid proxy server. Its working correctly as far as I can tell.

I have uptil now been using [zend2.com](http://zend2.com) whenever I need a proxy server. It allows me to visit websites using locations completely different from my original location. Can I do such a thing in squid?

I have turned `forwarded_for` to `off` and I think I have to use `forwarded_for` in some way to do this but can't figure it out.
Also, what else cool stuff can I do with squid proxy server ? I am new to proxy servers in general so anything you can tell me would be great :)

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Squid Cache: Version 3.5.12

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want all your local traffic to go from your squid to the zend2 server, or you expect without any cloud infrastructure and only your own squid to hide yourself?

Comment: I only want to use squid. I want to learn what I can do using just squid proxy setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend2 is a anonymous proxy service that will route your traffic through multiple locations, hiding your ip, and subsequently your location.  This is useful in many ways, but one in particular would be to get around geographical limitations for connecting to services.

Squid is a caching proxy mainly used for speeding up connections by caching files to be used again and again instead of downloading them each time you access that site.

While squid could be setup to do something similar to zend2, you would need the infrastructure to support it.  If you have a server running squid, all of your outbound connections would show from that one location.

Another alternative to zend2 would be to use the TOR project.

https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en